# Wait for Mass Transit saga to finish

Tags: c#, masstransit, request-response

I'm trying to create a saga that returns some result to the caller, just like the Request/Response pattern. I'm able to start the saga if I call the Send method, but not by submitting a Request.

So, the saga logic runs fine, but it doesn't return anything to the client.

Or submitting a Request gets processed by it's consumer and returns a response to the client, but never starts the saga.

**UPDATE:** The answer to [masstransit deferred respond in sagas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254310/masstransit-deferred-respond-in-sagas) doesn't seem to apply to my question for two reasons:

1) I wasn't able to start the saga by calling the Request method;

2) If I call the Send method to send the request and, later on, send the response, the caller thread does not wait for the response to get back before continuing to the next line of code;

**[END OF UPDATE]**

Please find the complete code [here](https://github.com/eduardomb08/MassTransit-SimpleRequestResponseSaga/tree/master/MassTransit-SimpleRequestResponseSaga). And below are the more relevant fragments:

Here is the saga class:

```cs
public class MySaga : MassTransitStateMachine<MySagaState>
    {
        public static Uri address = new Uri($"loopback://localhost/req_resp_saga");

        public Event<IStartSagaCommand> StartSaga { get; private set; }

        public Request<MySagaState, MyRequest, MyResponse> SomeRequest { get; private set; }

        public MySaga()
        {
            InstanceState(s => s.CurrentState);

            Event(() => StartSaga,
                cc =>
                    cc.CorrelateBy(state => state.Data, context => context.Message.Data)
                        .SelectId(context => Guid.NewGuid()));

            Request(() => SomeRequest, x => x.NullableCorrelationId, cfg =>
            {
                cfg.ServiceAddress = address;
                cfg.SchedulingServiceAddress = address;
                cfg.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            });

            Initially(
                When(StartSaga)
                    .Then(context =>
                    {
                        context.Instance.Data = context.Data.Data;
                    })
                    .ThenAsync(
                        context => Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Saga started: " +
                                                              $" {context.Data.Data} received"))
                    .Request(SomeRequest, context => new MyRequest() { CorrelationId = context.Instance.CorrelationId, RequestMessage = "Please do this" })
                    .TransitionTo(SomeRequest.Pending)
                    .ThenAsync(context => Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Transition completed: " +
                                                                     $" {(context.Instance.CurrentState == SomeRequest.Pending ? "pending" : "done")} received"))
                    //.Then(context =>
                    //{
                    //    var endpoint = context.GetSendEndpoint(address).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    //    endpoint.Send(new MyResponse() { CorrelationId = context.Instance.CorrelationId, ResponseMessage = "Your wish is my command" });
                    //})
            );

            During(SomeRequest.Pending,
                When(SomeRequest.Completed)
                    .ThenAsync(
                        context => Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Saga ended: " +
                                                              $" {context.Data.ResponseMessage} received"))
                    .Finalize()
            );
        }
    }
```

This starts the saga but doesn't wait for it to finish and respond:

```cs
            var address = new Uri($"loopback://localhost/req_resp_saga");
            var endPoint = bus.GetSendEndpoint(address)
                .Result;

            endPoint.Send<IStartSagaCommand>(new { Data = "Hello World!!" });
```

And this waits for a response but doesn't involve the saga at all:

```cs
var address = new Uri($"loopback://localhost/req_resp_saga");
            var requestClient = new MessageRequestClient<MyRequest, MyResponse>(bus, address, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            var response = requestClient.Request(new MyRequest() { CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid(), RequestMessage = "Please do this" })
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();
```

How can I have the caller start the saga and wait for it to finish and do something with its reponse?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254310/masstransit-deferred-respond-in-sagas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [masstransit deferred respond in sagas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254310/masstransit-deferred-respond-in-sagas)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your comments. I've looked at that question before (I should have mentioned that) but it is not clear to me that its the same as mine. If I call Send to start the saga asynchronously, the caller thread is free to execute the next statement and doesn't wait for a response. I want it to wait. If I call the Request method, the thread waits for the response, but it's the consumers that process the request, and not the Saga. I want to be able to build more complex workflows and use sagas to control it and be able to compensate for any faults.

Comment: After fixing the error described in my answer below, I was finally able to understand the similarities between my question and the one on the link you provided. It is really the same scenario. I agree now that this is a duplicate; although I still think there are some nuances that aren't clear on the links answers. Thanks again, @ChrisPatterson and AlexeyZimarev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the solution myself.

The problem was that I was confused about how to trigger the saga with a Request call. I thought I had to declare a

```cs
Request<in TInstance, TRequest, TResponse>
```

(Automatonimous)

That was not working for me.

And the Event I used to start the saga had it's own interface

```cs
Event<IStartSaga>
```

which was not the same I was using when calling the Request method

```cs
var requestClient = new MessageRequestClient<MyRequest, MyResponse>(bus, address, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            var response = requestClient.Request(new MyRequest() { CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid(), RequestMessage = "Please do this" })
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();
```

So the fix was to change the declaration of the event to

```cs
Event<MyRequest>
```

Now the saga starts whenever I call Request with a MyResquest message. And the caller waits for the response from the saga.

I made some other changes to clean up the code a little and pushed it to github too.

Comment: Hey this Request is is request from state machine OR request from client to saga state machine ?